# load asp.net datagrid faster

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net data grid which pulls large amount of data and takes some time to load.

Is there a way to make it load faster.

I am ok with paging ..to show first 10 records on initial page load and then rest.

Comment: First of all how are you Loading the data initially? is there a query that you are using..? can you show the existing code..?

Comment: what did you try so far? have you checked out this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085410/how-to-enable-paging-and-sorting-on-asp-net-4-0-gridview-programmatically

Comment: here's something I found on google when searching for `datagrid pagination`:  http://www.justskins.com/forums/datagrid-pagination-29822.html

Comment: I am getting data from web service and data source is a list.

Comment: have you thought about using a `DataSet` but I would be interested to see how you are defining the List, perhaps there are other Collections you could utilize or even a `Hashset` which is extremely fast not to mention it allows duplicates if necessary.. but would need to see some `CODE..!`

Comment: It's unlikely that the datagrid itself is "slow". You need to establish which part (or parts) of the operation is slow. Maybe the slow bit is a the web service you're retrieving data from?