# GridView in multiple pages

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I show my grid data in 2 or more pages?

Say, on my page load I have the grid, below which I have some range of numbers as hyperlinks(1,2,...). When I click 2 it should open the data of the gridview in the second page.

How do I do this?

Comment: use pager and fetch data from database in every pager index click

Comment: Get LinkId and pass it to another page and fetch the data from DB based on Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Reference Link**](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-send-gridview-row-values-to.html)

```
<a href ='<%#"UpdateGridviewvalues.aspx?UserId="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UserId") %>'> <%#Eval("UserName") %>  </a>
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

There are many example on the net which can help you in this. One of them are following

1. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-Example.aspx
2. [How to enable Paging and Sorting on ASP.NET 4.0 GridView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085410/how-to-enable-paging-and-sorting-on-asp-net-4-0-gridview-programmatically)
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28910/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering