# How to page gridview that already has data bound to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a View button on my webpage. As soon as a user clicks on this button, through a web service data is fetched and then data is bound to grid view. But when the grid view loads it only shows the number of rows mentioned in PageSize property of the grid and does not show page numbers.

```
private void FetchData(ref DataTable dt)
{
    string s_strResult = "";
    string s_strQuery = "";
    string s_strQueryType = "";

    try
    {                    
        grdSearchResult.DataSource = dt.DataSet.Tables["Result"];
        grdSearchResult.DataBind();
        tblSearchResult.Visible = true;            
        lblSearchResult.Text = "Total Items:" + dt.DataSet.Tables["Result"].Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

The Result DataSet contains 5000 rows with 30 columns each. When the gridView loads all I can see is just 100 records (as PageSize=100). How can I page the results? The data needs to be fetched at button click only. The code for gridView page index change is as follows:

```
protected void grdSearchResult_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            grdSearchResult.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            grdSearchResult.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayMessage(GlobalClass.enumMsgType.Error, ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your asp.net markup code?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to fetch all the records at once or you want to fetch the only first 100 records first and then on pagination click fetch another records.  If you want to fetch only first 100 records, then how will know the total records. Kindly provide more details about the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable Paging and Sorting on ASP.NET 4.0 GridView programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085410/how-to-enable-paging-and-sorting-on-asp-net-4-0-gridview-programmatically)

Comment: शेखर.. I fetched all the data on view button click. The data has been bound to a grid. Suppose if the data table contains 3000 records (verified and checked on run time) and the grid's page size is 100, then only one page with 100 records is shown. The rest 2900 entries do not show up.

Comment: @scartag The gridview looks like: <asp:GridView ID="grdSearchResult" runat="server" SkinID="gvSkin" OnPageIndexChanging="grdSearchResult_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdSearchResult_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100" Width="100%" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast">

Answer (score 0):

Hello Rishik please check below link for gridview paging:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/816953/How-To-Implement-Paging-in-GridView-Control-in-ASP

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in a `Viewstate` or `Session` variable, I recommend to use a property as wrapper like this:

```
private DataTable dtStored
{
    get { return (ViewState["dt"] == null) ? null : (DataTable)ViewState["dt"]; }
    set { ViewState["dt"] = value; }
}
```

now you can bind your DataTable and save it in the property:

```
private void FetchData(ref DataTable dt)
{
    string s_strResult = "";
    string s_strQuery = "";
    string s_strQueryType = "";

    try
    {                    
        dtStored = dt.DataSet.Tables["Result"];
        grdSearchResult.DataSource = dtStored;
        grdSearchResult.DataBind();
        tblSearchResult.Visible = true;            
        lblSearchResult.Text = "Total Items:" + dt.DataSet.Tables["Result"].Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

and in the IndexPageChanging method just add a line:

```
protected void grdSearchResult_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            grdSearchResult.DataSource = dtStored;
            grdSearchResult.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            grdSearchResult.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayMessage(GlobalClass.enumMsgType.Error, ex.Message);
        }
}
```

If your data is too large maybe it could be better to store it in a `Session` variable than in a `Viewstate`, because the second one is going to travel from the Client to the Server and from the Server to the Client in every Postback while you stay in the same page or until you set the variable to `null`

Comment: I stored my data table in session variable as I do not want it to be sent at every postback to server adding overheads. On quick watch, I could verify that the session variable had all the values of the data table. But still the index numbers are not being displayed. And if index numbers are not displayed, the IndexChange event will not be fired.

Comment: did you add the AllowPaging="True" attribute to your Gridview control in the aspx?

Comment: Yeah, you may see the markup code that I have shared earlier in other comments.