# Total Record count and paging on the same line in an asp.net gridview but not in the footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I must have done this in my past, and what I am asking for is very simple but for the life of me I cannot remember nor can I find anything online to help me. I have an asp.net gridview and I have basic bog standard pagnation via the numeric settings (I actually just style this to the look I want, but does the job). I would however like to add a record count in the same paging row. I know I can add a footer and add a template for it, however firstly I do not want to redevelop something that already works and secondly some of my grids which do not have paging also have a drag & drop feature so I really do not want to start adding a footer to my grid. What I get currently is a paging row which is styled to my needs, all I want to do is add a label or something in it so I can add a count like 1 to 10, 11 to 20 and so on. Does anyone have a clue how to do this but not in the footer.

Comment: Does this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4087676/6768729

Comment: not really, as I know how to complete paging. What I want is in the paging row to have a simple x number of records found. I know the code behind what I do not know is how to implement this on the asp.net webform as I am trying to avoid creating a new page style template on the grid cause I will have to re invent the wheel so to speak with the paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for anyone else who ever has a problem I managed to get around this issue by creating two labels in the in VB.NET/C# (does not matter which language) and add it to the row in the gridview RowDataBound.

First look for the row type to be pager

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Pager Then
```

Create a couple of labels, cells in which these labels will go into and a table row so these cells have somewhere to go.

```
 Dim TotalRecords As New Label
 Dim TotalPages As New Label
 Dim Row As TableRow = TryCast(e.Row, TableRow)
 Dim Cell1 As New TableCell
 Dim Cell2 As New TableCell
```

Add the text to each label

```
TotalRecords.Text = ctype(gridview.DataSource, DataView).Table.Rows.Count & " total records"
TotalPages.Text = "Page " & (gridview.PageIndex + 1) & " of " gridview.PageCount
```

Then add these labels to the cells

```
Cell1.Controls.Add(TotalRecords)
Cell2.Controls.Add(TotalPages.Text)
```

Now add these cells to our pager row (this can be done in any order but I wanted *Total records ----Pages--- Page n of x*)

```
Row.Controls.AddAt(0, Cell1)
Row.Controls.Add(Cell2)
```

This will add two extra td in the pager row so in the HTML we end up with

```
<tr class="Pager">
 <td><span>n total records</span></td>
 <td></td>
 <td><span>Page n of n</span></td>
</tr>
```

So ideally you would add a class to the paging style which can be done in asp.net but the PagerStyle css. You can if you want also style each td by adding a class to the cell object.

```
Cell1.CssClass = "Style1"
Cell2.CssClass = "Style2"
```

Once the cells have been added to the row then you will have 3 controls so for any spacing issues you can start to use column span as well.